# Self Answered Questions with "Little Research"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-quality, instant-self-answer

There was [this question ("How to identify certain rows within a specified range of columns?")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952753/identifying-rows-that-have-code-within-list-of-columns) in [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) that I did not know the appropriate action for.

1. I couldn't find a duplicate that fit the bill.
2. I (personally) don't think a downvote is necessary as the hover tooltip reads "this question does not show *any* research effort..." as the OP showed what they tried and was very close.
3. It seems like they asked the question and answered immediately which would make me seem they just didn't try "hard enough" before posting?
4. I honestly think this post *can* help others in the future and follows [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

What would be the "correct" action here. My personal gut feeling is to just "leave as is", but want to ask others - what do we do with questions that seem like the OP should've just tried a little harder before posting?

I'm not sure if it was the Meta effect, but since this posting a comment was posted just afterwards that I'm unsure if that is the correct action or if that holds any validity.

Comment: The OP doesn't actually say what the *problem* with their attempt is, therefore it's off topic for lack of MCVE.

Comment: *what do we do with questions that seem like the OP should've just tried a little harder before posting?* We allow self-answered Q&A here so the time between asking and answering isn't relevant. All the normal rules apply.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The value of any question & answer set is searchability, and this is especially true for a self answered question, because you are trying to help people with the same problem find the solution that worked for you.

In this specific case, the OP does a fair job describing what they are trying to accomplish, and shows their code, and their dataset.  But they are missing one extremely important piece:

### They fail to describe what is or isn't working.

Without that critical piece of information, they make it virtually impossible for someone running into the same issue to find the question via searching (whether it is search with Google (or search engine of choice) or from within Stack Overflow).

So the appropriate course of action is to vote to close as "Unclear what you are asking" or "Off Topic > Why isn't this code working".  You could be helpful to the OP and leave a comment explaining why you voted to close, and encourage them to edit their question to add this information.